# Missing Bitcode while Archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, bitcode, archiving

While archiving build I got this error, I tried clearing derived data , cleaned Xcode still same issue [image]

Comment: In the target's Build Settings, Do you have "Enable BitCode" set to YES?

Comment: No Its No only for all targets

Answer (score 0):

In the target's Build Settings, set "Enable BitCode" to YES.